# Editing assembly in WinDbg

Tags: assembly, windbg, cracking, ollydbg

I have been trying to solve some "crackmes" (from http://crackmes.de) using WinDbg. Most of the solutions I have looked at involve using Olly Dbg to make modifications to the assembly; is there a way to do this in WinDbg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **a** command:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538153(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can view the assembly code using the disassembly window and disassemble code using `u` command:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and more info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx